# Using python turtle GUI

Tags: python

i am currently learning how to use gui as i want to continue on to using logic gates in gui and i was playing around with some code and got stuck on how i could shorten acode like this.

```
from turtle import *
for x in range(2):
    for i in range(3):
        left(90)
        forward(90)
        right(90)
        forward(90)

    right(180)

penup()    
goto(180, 0)
pendown()

for x in range(2):
    for i in range(3):
        left(90)
        forward(90)
        right(90)
        forward(90)

    right(180)

penup() 
goto(360, 0)
pendown()

for x in range(2):
    for i in range(3):
        left(90)
        forward(90)
        right(90)
        forward(90)

    right(180)
```

Comment: There's no way to short code. [Here](https://github.com/Istiakshovon/drawLove/blob/master/main.py) I drew [love](https://github.com/Istiakshovon/drawLove/blob/master/main.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use functions to group blocks of code, you then can call these functions to reduce duplication of code for example,

```py
from turtle import *


def myFunction():
    for x in range(2):
        for i in range(3):
            left(90)
            forward(90)
            right(90)
            forward(90)

        right(180)


myFunction()
penup() 
goto(180, 0)
pendown()

myFunction()
penup()
goto(360, 0)
pendown()

myFunction()
```

If you needed to vary the angles or number of times you can parse in variables to the functions,

```py
def myFunction(angle, xrange, irange):
    for x in range(xrange):
        for i in range(irange):
            left(angle)
            forward(angle)
            right(angle)
            forward(angle)

        right(180)
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the awnser i just needed to change the goto to a forward and right.

```
from turtle import *
penup()
goto(-300, 0)
pendown()
for y in range(3):
    for x in range(2):
        for i in range(3):
            left(90)
            forward(90)
            right(90)
            forward(90)

        right(180)


    penup()
    right(360)
    forward(180)
    pendown()
```